# Echo out <select> instead of checkbox

Tags: php

```
<li>
<strong>Eye Colour:</strong><br/>
<?php
// Set up values to filter for.
$eyes = array(
    'blue' => 'Blue',
    'brown' => 'Brown',
    'hazel'=> 'Hazel' ,
    'grey' => 'Grey',
    'amber' => 'Amber',
    );
foreach ( $eyes as $key => $value ) {
    // Check if this value should default to be checked.
    $checked_modifier = '';
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['eyes'] ) && in_array( $key, $_REQUEST['eyes'] ) ) {
        $checked_modifier = ' checked';
    }
    

// Add checkbox.
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="eyes[]" value="' . $key . '"' . $checked_modifier . '><label> ' . $value . '</label><br/>';
}
?>
</li>
```

Comment: Echo `<select>` before the loop. Echo `<option>` inside the loop. Echo `</select>` after the loop.

Comment: Use `selected` instead of `checked` for the options in `$_REQUEST['eyes']`